# Reversed view of ImmutableSortedSet

Tags: java, set, guava, immutability

Guava has `ImmutableSortedSet` which nicely provides ordering and immutability.

What I am looking for is a simple utility method for such a set which would give me access to the elements in reversed order, similar to `Lists.reverse(List)`.

I've looked at `Sets` as well as in `Collections2` but to no avail. I can easily write one myself, but this sounds like a logical feature to be present in guava anyway. Or maybe such a method exists but I'm just blind?

Answer (score 8, accepted):

[`ImmutableSortedSet.descendingSet()`](https://google.github.io/guava/releases/snapshot-jre/api/docs/com/google/common/collect/ImmutableSortedSet.html#descendingSet--) returns a view of an `ImmutableSortedSet` in descending order, just like for any other NavigableSet.

Alternately, if you want to create the `ImmutableSortedSet` with descending order from the beginning, use a builder created by `ImmutableSortedSet.reverseOrder()`.

Answer (score 3):

According to the Guava docs, ImmutableSortedSet has a static method `reverseOrder` which should do what you want...  [Guava JavaDoc](http://docs.guava-libraries.googlecode.com/git/javadoc/com/google/common/collect/ImmutableSortedSet.html#reverseOrder%28%29)

Comment: That method is a little different, as Louis explains.

Answer (score 0):

It will give you a list, not a set, but

```
set.asList().reverse()
```

would do the trick.

Answer (score -1):

try

```
TreeSet(Comparator<? super E> comparator)
```

http://docs.oracle.com/javase/6/docs/api/java/util/TreeSet.html#TreeSet(java.util.Comparator)